# Windows Phone 8.1 WinRT Page Custom Transitions

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime

Is there a way in Windows Phone 8.1 RT to code my own page transitions and how low level and fancy can I get?

I'm not talking about being able to pick between sliding and turnstile transitions. More like coding a custom shader that uses a bit mask to interpolate between two frames over time.

Say i wan't to create a transition that burns the top page away.

I've tried to google some tutorials but I am having a hard time finding any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably take a look at combining `DirectX` with `XAML`, for which you have plenty of resources online. This is the lowest you can get, and super powerful. For `C#` there is a popular wrapper called [SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org/) which could make things easier.

Another option could be the [Win2D](https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D) API.

Additionally you should reimplement the `Frame` control which would handle the new content animations properly.

Seems like a lot of work tough.

Comment: Hi Kristian, thank you for your input. I've looked up WP WinRT Toolkit which heavily depend on SharpDX and it looks good an seems its the way to go. And yeah a lot of work :)